# Current date with autofill Google Doc from a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To insert the current date in a Google Doc template automatically filled from a Sheet, I had to create a column that only states the current date...

This is the script that I use:

```js
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[2]).toLocaleDateString();
body.replaceText('{{Data}}', friendlyDate);
```

I want to do it directly from the script, with no need for that date column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be possible. Go with `Utilities.formatDate` so you can also format your date and pass your timeZone manually, or get it via `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`

```
body.replaceText('{{Data}}', Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy"));
```